# Cannot delete sheets with workbookopen method

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping someone can help me out. I have tried the following delete methods as a module and it works perfectly. However, putting it into `Sub Workbook_Open()` and it fails with a run time error

> "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

The code is as below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Application.UserName = "Persons Username" Then
    Sheets("Con").Visible = True
    Sheets("BPStdx").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheets("NewSheet").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheets("Lookups").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheets("BAs") = xlVeryHidden
    Else
        Sheets("Con").Visible = True
        Sheets("BPStdx").Visible = True
        Sheets("Lookups").Visible = True
        Sheets("BAs") = True
        Sheets("NewSheet").Activate

'stepping through this is where I get the run-time error        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BPStdx").Delete
        Sheets("Con").Delete
        Sheets("Lookups").Delete
        Sheets("BAs").Delete
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have missed `Sheets("BAs") = True` it should be `Sheets("BAs").Visible = True` and here also `Sheets("BAs") = xlVeryHidden` to  `Sheets("BAs").Visible = xlVeryHidden`

Comment: @HafizSb thanks for that. just needed a fresh set of eyes. I cannot believe I missed the ".visible" on BAs. Hanging my head in shame